# Error Nest.js Microservices, can not import module of RabbitMQ

Tags: node.js, module, rabbitmq, microservices, nestjs

Here I have separate module which represents RabbitMQ client module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Transport, ClientsModule } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { ServiceConfig } from '../config/service.config';
import { RmqSubscriberServiceToken } from '../../constants/token.constant';
import { ConfigModule } from '../config/config.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.registerAsync([
      {
        name: RmqSubscriberServiceToken,
        useFactory: (config: ServiceConfig) => ({
          transport: Transport.RMQ,
          options: {
            urls: [
              `amqp://${config.rabbitmq.User}:${config.rabbitmq.Password}@${config.rabbitmq.Host}`,
            ],
            queue: config.rabbitmq.QueueName,
            queueOptions: {
              durable: true,
            },
          },
        }),
        imports: [ConfigModule],
        inject: [ServiceConfig],
      },
    ]),
  ],
})
export class RmqSubscriberModule {}
```

When I import this into my service Module I get the following error

```
Error: Cannot find module '@nestjs/core/helpers/optional-require'
Require stack:
- /home/rharutyunyan/workspace/roulette/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/nest-microservice.js
- /home/rharutyunyan/workspace/roulette/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/index.js
- /home/rharutyunyan/workspace/roulette/common/lib/services/rabbitmq/rmq-subscriber.module.js
- /home/rharutyunyan/workspace/roulette/common/lib/services/rabbitmq/index.js
```

Can someone pls explain what is the problem here ?

Comment: `@nestjs/core` is installed, right?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel yes it is installed, any ideas what can be the problem, I event import directly this clientsModule into my service module imports and it does not work (

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, the problem was in versions, my @nestjs/core version was different from microservices